# java,returning null value from method

Tags: java

I need to return finalString value for input operator name.
where,internalPrestring is fixed for specific operator,internalDigit would be retrieved from getting operator name.then all of'em would be added to finalString.
but it is giving null, i can't understand the problem

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.lang.*;

 class CallManager
 {


   public static final String postString = "#";

   StringBuilder stringBuilder;

   String internalPreString;
   String preString;
   String middleString;
   String finalString;
   String operatorName;


   int internalDigit;



   //needs to set oprator name
   public void setOperatorName( String getMeFromPreferences)
   {

    operatorName = getMeFromPreferences;
        System.out.println("I got it " + operatorName);
   }


//afeter having operator name need to set inrernal digit for each operator
public void setOperatorBasedInternalDigit(int getIntegerForOperator)
    {
        internalDigit = getIntegerForOperator;
        System.out.println("I got it too " + internalDigit);
    }

//it needs to get string from ocr  
public void setString( String getMeFromOCR )
    {
        middleString = getMeFromOCR;
    }


//preString creator for differnet operator
public String getOperatorBasedPreString(String operatorName)
{
        if(operatorName.equals("Airtel"))
        internalPreString = "787";

        else if(operatorName.equals("Banglalink"))
        internalPreString = "123";

        else if(operatorName.equals("Grameen"))
        internalPreString = "555";

        else if(operatorName.equals("Robi"))
        internalPreString = "111";

        else if(operatorName.equals("TeleTalk"))
        internalPreString = "151";


        stringBuilder.append("*").append(internalPreString).append("*");
        preString = stringBuilder.toString();

        return preString;

}

//get operator name and retrive midlle string's digit size from it
public int getOperatorBasedInternalDigit( String operatorName)
{

        if(operatorName.matches("^Airtel | Grameen | Robi$"))
        internalDigit = 16; 

        else if(operatorName.matches("^Banglalink$"))
        internalDigit = 14;

        else if(operatorName.matches("^TeleTalk$"))
        internalDigit = 13;


        return internalDigit;
}

//check operator-based digit number with input middle string as a number then retrive final string
public String getString( String toBeInserted, int inetrnalDigit)
    {

        if(toBeInserted.length() == internalDigit)
        {

            int counter = 0;
            char [] insertHere  = new char[internalDigit];

            for(int verifier = 0; verifier < internalDigit; verifier ++)
            {
                insertHere[verifier] = toBeInserted.charAt(verifier);
                    if(!Character.isDigit(insertHere[verifier]))
                    break;

            counter ++;
            }

            if(counter == internalDigit)
            {

                    stringBuilder.append(preString).append(toBeInserted).append(postString);
                    finalString = stringBuilder.toString();
                    //to see what i've got finally as input for using this call manager method.it would be removed too
                    System.out.println(finalString);
                    return finalString;
            }

            else
            {
                //this printing could be used in main program
                System.out.println("number is less or more than desired ..... INVALID SCAN");
                System.out.println(middleString);
                //here i will call the method for scan the card again
                //
                //
                   return middleString;
             }
          }


          else
              {
                //this printing could be used in main program
                System.out.println("number is less or more than desired ..... INVALID SCAN");
                System.out.println(middleString);
                //here i will call the method for scan the card again
                //
                //
                return middleString;
              }



    }


}


//tester class that CallManager works rightly or not
class CallManagerDemo
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));



          System.out.println("Enter name of Operator");
          CallManager clm = new CallManager();

          clm.setOperatorName("Banglalink");
          System.out.println(clm.internalPreString);
          System.out.println(clm.preString);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having only four lines that deals with your `CallManager` class:

```
CallManager clm = new CallManager();
clm.setOperatorName("Banglalink");
System.out.println(clm.internalPreString);
System.out.println(clm.preString);
```

The reason why you are getting null :

1. You are using a default constructor right and there processing is
   done in it. So this is not a problem
2. Now on next line you call `setOperator` method which has this code:

   ```
   public void setOperatorName( String getMeFromPreferences)  
   {  
      operatorName = getMeFromPreferences;  
      System.out.println("I got it " + operatorName);  
   }
   ```

   Now here you are only setting thw variable `operatorName` and nothing else. So all other variables are null as you not doing any processing or something that will initialize them to something.
3. So when you print `clm.internalPreString` and `clm.preString` you get null as they are not initialized. But try printing `clm.operatorName` and it will print the operator name that you passed and was initialzed inside your method `setOperatorName`.

So as you have defined so many method inside your class, use them so that all the variables are set as per your logic

**UPDATE**

```
public void setOperatorName( String getMeFromPreferences)  
{  
     operatorName = getMeFromPreferences;  

     //call any methods for example and use the values returned from the method by storing it inside a variable 
     String mystring = getOperatorBasedPreString(String operatorName) 
}
```

Comment: after setting an operator name wont it retrieve internalDigit size and inetrnalPrestring from getOperatorBasedInternalDigit( String operatorName) and getOperatorBasedPreString(String operatorName) ? would you clear me that?

Comment: No you need to call those methods inside `setOperatorName` method or somewhere, it won't call it automatically

Comment: how to call these methods inside the method? any suggestion?

Comment: if i put exactly this in it shows Error: illegal start of expression    String mystring = getOperatorBasedPreString(String operatorName); if i do like this    String mystring = getOperatorBasedPreString(operatorName); works fine. but when i call mystring in     String getOperatorBasedPreString(String mystring) after run it shows null pointer exception    java.lang.NullPointerException
 at CallManager.getOperatorBasedPreString(CallManagerDemo.java:79)
 at CallManager.setOperatorName(CallManagerDemo.java:41)
 at CallManagerDemo.main(CallManagerDemo.java:176)

Comment: one more other thing,can you please help? when you write something in comments, i have to reload the page every time to see new comments.i'm new in this site.so i dont know - how to get knocked automatically when new post comes!!! and when i ask a question to this site.how do you get notified,that new question came!

Comment: See the upper left corner and click on **StackExchange** and inside that click on **inbox** to know if someone left a comment on your question/answer or gave an answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think that you should call any of the function instead of the string variables using object.

You are just calling one function that is

```
public void setOperatorName(String getMeFromPreferences) {

        operatorName = getMeFromPreferences;
        System.out.println("I got it " + operatorName);
    }
```

You are calling default constructor with out any variable setting there,
You had not initialized any String you are calling form object.

I think you should call any of the function e-g

```
public int getOperatorBasedInternalDigit(String operatorName)
```

OR

```
public String getString(String toBeInserted, int inetrnalDigit)
```

Then you will get some string as you are expecting ...
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have never set the values for the variables for those you are getting the NULL value.The terms get/set must be used where an attribute is accessed directly.Read [Java Programming Style GuideLines](http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html) For more clarity.Use appropriate getters and setter for getting and setting the value like you have done for operatorName.